# POCO where is the HTTPSClientSession?

Tags: c++, openssl, poco-libraries

After building POCO lib,I find that I can't use `HTTPSClientSession` class ,then 
I search it from google anywhere,finding that OpenSSL is not builded by me.It takes me about a full
 day to handle it,but I failed.Can any guy give me some usefull steps in details?Thank you!
Key words:`NetSSL_OpenSSL`

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question how far you've made it on your own... did you download the "complete" edition of POCO? Did you download and build OpenSSL? Do you know how to tell your compiler to search for your OpenSSL library and include files ?

Comment: Firstly,after building OpenSSL,I didn't find `lib` dir. Secondly,I add 
`NetSSL_OpenSSL` string into `components` file in POCO root.Thirdly,I modified the openssl home dir in `buildwin.cmd` file.At last,in progress of building ,this is no corresponding `openssl` to be seen and the result is like that ,no `NetSSL_OpenSSL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `Win32OpenSSL-1_0_0j.exe`(or other version),you'd better install it in `C://`.Then downloading full POCO soruce code (must full,containing NetSSL_OpenSSL directory).Finally,build it.Over!